# Like expload function in pyspark. Need to sort list of dicts by some VALUE in that dict to coresponding column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am facing issue with chanigng schema of my pyspark df.
In dataframe is nested field called incident_tags. This is list of dicts `[{k11:v11, k12:v12, k13:v13, k14:v14},{k21:v21, k22:v22, k23:v23, k24:v24},...].`

[example of incident_tags data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwHQv.png)

I need to put each dict in to different column based on vale of NAME key in the dict.
For example:

`{id": "assignment_level", "name": "assignment_level", "type": "Text", "value": "2"}` -> to column `assignment_level`

`{"id": "automation_id", "name": "automation_id", "type": "Text", "value": "Automation reference"}` -> to column `automation_id`

`{"id": "knowledge_id", "name": "knowledge_id", "type": "Text", "value": ""}` -> to column `knowledge_id`

All columns with possible values of names are created allready.
Many thanks for any adivces!

I tried to convert this nested field to string and work based on it, but it is complecated and not efficient in terms of compute solution, also try explode function from pyspark - but didn't have success

Input

incident_tags   automation_id   knowledge_id    Region  PRC reportedon_system   impact  urgency
"[
0:{""id"": ""automation_id"", ""name"": ""automation_id"", ""type"": ""Text"", ""value"": ""Automation reference""},
1:{""id"": ""prc"", ""name"": ""PRC"", ""type"": ""Text"", ""value"": """"},
2:{""id"": ""knowledge_id"", ""name"": ""knowledge_id"", ""type"": ""Text"", ""value"": """"},
3:{""id"": ""region"", ""name"": ""Region"", ""type"": ""MultiValue"", ""value"": ""europe""},
4:{""id"": ""reportedon_system"", ""name"": ""reportedon_system"", ""type"": ""Text"", ""value"": """"}
]"
"[
0:{""id"": ""impact"", ""name"": ""impact"", ""type"": ""Text"", ""value"": ""4""},
1:{""id"": ""urgency"", ""name"": ""urgency"", ""type"": ""Text"", ""value"": """"},
2:{""id"": ""region"", ""name"": ""Region"", ""type"": ""Text"", ""value"": ""geo-data""},
]"

**Input:**

| incident_tags | automation_id | knowledge_id | Region | PRC | reportedon_system | impact | urgency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ 0:{"id": "automation_id", "name": "automation_id", "type": "Text", "value": "Automation reference"}, 1:{"id": "prc", "name": "PRC", "type": "Text", "value": ""}, 2:{"id": "knowledge_id", "name": "knowledge_id", "type": "Text", "value": ""}, 3:{"id": "region", "name": "Region", "type": "MultiValue", "value": "europe"}, 4:{"id": "reportedon_system", "name": "reportedon_system", "type": "Text", "value": ""} ] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| [ 0:{"id": "impact", "name": "impact", "type": "Text", "value": "4"}, 1:{"id": "urgency", "name": "urgency", "type": "Text", "value": ""}, 2:{"id": "region", "name": "Region", "type": "Text", "value": "geo-data"} ] |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

**Output:**

| incident_tags | automation_id | knowledge_id | Region | PRC | reportedon_system | impact | urgency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [ 0:{"id": "aid", "name": "automation_id", "type": "Text", "value": "ref"}, 1:{"id": "prc", "name": "PRC", "type": "Text", "value": ""} ] | {"id": "aid", "name": "automation_id", "type": "Text", "value": "ref"} |  |  | {"id": "prc", "name": "PRC", "type": "Text", "value": ""} |  |  |  |
| [ 0:{"id": "imp", "name": "impact", "type": "Text", "value": "4"}, 1:{"id": "urg", "name": "urgency", "type": "Text", "value": ""}, 2:{"id": "reg", "name": "Region", "type": "Text", "value": "geo"} ] |  |  | {"id": "reg", "name": "Region", "type": "Text", "value": "geo"} |  |  | {"id": "imp", "name": "impact", "type": "Text", "value": "4"} | {"id": "urg", "name": "urgency", "type": "Text", "value": ""} |

Comment: Please give as sample input and output here, not an image.

Comment: valid point, thanks. Provided in/outputs